# Sanity GROQ query to not return nullish values

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, sanity, groq

I was querying `Sanity` with `GROQ` and wanted to get response excluding `nullish` values in case there is no `image url` is available but if it is then return the `image url`.

Doing like this:

```
defined(image) => {image},
```

Wanted to get

```
image:"png image url here"
```

but getting

```
"image": {
  "_type": "file",
  "asset": {
    "_ref": "abc-png",
    "_type": "reference"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by myself:

If we want to get `image: "image url here"` in case there is image coming from Sanity, then doing like this

```rb
defined(image) => {"image":image.asset->url}
```

will send you `image:"image url here"` but if it is not coming and value is `null` then it will not send the attribute at all.

Hope this will be helpful!